# Access GooglePay / ApplePay transactions in mobile (flutter) app

Tags: payment, mobile-development, google-pay

Does anybody know, if there is a way to access the transactions made from (Google/Apple)Pay on the device?

I think of a way where the user first needs to grant the access to a specific card on his wallet to the app, before the sync is then started.

I am looking for a way to somehow verificate billings, which are initiated by our app, without handling the payment process itself. So I just want to "observe" it.

Thanks alot for any advice in the correct direction

I've been researching several different API gateway solutions to process payments, or to access bank account records, but that's all not really what the users will feel comfortable with.